# Recurring Error in Update Manager - Could Not Initialize The Package Manager

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, software-center, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix this “E:Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Please refer to the attached screen-shot. This error comes every time I boot and now I am unable to get any updates.

Also, the Ubuntu Software Center will no longer work. I click on the USC icon and nothing happens.

> Could not initialize the package
>   information An unresolvable problem
>   occurred while initializing the
>   package information. Please report
>   this bug against the 'update-manager'
>   package and include the following
>   error message:
>
> 'E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 61
>   in source list /etc/apt/sources.list'

I am using Maverick Meercat Netbook. Please advise how to resolve this problem.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT - [LINK](http://paste.ubuntu.com/531519/) to the sources.list file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was:

> 'E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 61
>   in source list /etc/apt/sources.list'

Thanks for provide us the pastebin of your [source list](http://paste.ubuntu.com/531519/). After look at it, I could certainly identify where is the problem. Look at the screenshot below:

[image]

The lines that need to be purged out of the file are highlighted in the image above. Now lets remove it (follow up the instructions below):

- Open a Terminal and type `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Go to line 61 and remove from line 61 (starting with `sudo`) until line 64 (where you will see `exit`).
- Save and exit from gedit. Go back to your terminal and type: `sudo apt-get update`

Now you can proceed :-)

Would be very nice for your skills if you spending a little time reading some docs about syntax of repository files and its configuration. learn how Ubuntu works will make you a better user every day, including able to collaborate. Here are two links that will help with your journey in Ubuntu:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SourcesList

[**EDITED**]

Please help us to see you `/etc/apt/sources.list`: Submit your `sources.list` file at the [Ubuntu Official Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), after edit this Ask to include the link. Thanks!

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/531519/

Comment: Here is the link to the list file.

Comment: Delete not sudo but all 61 line - its nonsense here

Comment: I just deleted the entire 61st line. Error still persists and Software Center still doesn't shows up. :'(

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. It worked. And those links are really helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

As it says, you have a mistake in your sources list.

To open the sources list in Gedit Text Editor, open a Terminal and input the command:
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.

When the sources list is open look at line 61. Do you see a mistake? You can make this line ineffective by putting at the beginning of the line: #

If you can't see a mistake, or it is too difficult for you, Copy and Paste the list here.

Comment: The 61st line was as follows. I placed a # rebooted after saving the file, but problem persists.

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 886DDD89