# How do I remove a broken software source?

Tags: unity, lubuntu, lxde

I accidentally added this in a terminal:

```
sudo wget http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/gutsy.list -0 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
```

after which I get this error:

```
E:not known on line 1 file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
E:Could not read source list
etc...etc...
```

I saw that you already 'solved a similar problem ...
can you help me

Original (italian):

gestore pacchetti bloccato

Ho inserito per sbaglio questo comando nel terminale:

```
sudo wget http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/gutsy.list -0 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
dopodiche si e'bloccato gestione pacchetto e ricevo questo errore:
E:non riconosciuto alla riga 1nel file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
E:impossibile leggere elenco sorgenti
etc...etc...
```

ho visto che hai gia' risolto un problema simile...
mi puoi aiutare

Comment: What is the content of the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list? Have you tried removing it and doind the apt-get update again?

Comment: Related: [How do I fix this “E:Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of ubuntu are you using? You tried to add the gusty repository which was from something like ubuntu 7.10. So open the dialog where you can change your software sources (depends on which ubuntu youre using).

- Synaptic - Settings>Repositories>Other Sources
- Software Centre - Edit>Software sources>Other Sources

Remove the medibuntu sources from the list. Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to add medibuntu correctly then use this command

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Comment: sto' usando lubuntu 11.10 lxde con synaptic-repository-altre fonti.

Comment: cosa devo fare per rimuovere medibuntu dalla lista per poi poter usare il comando seguente di update ? cmq grazie per aiuto

Comment: later on i understood how remove medibuntu from the list, but since i tried to put sudo apt-get update, it asked me a password that it was impossible to insert why ?

Comment: i removed medibuntu sources from the list but, by the time i tried to digit sudo apt-get update and pushed enter, it was blocked with [sudo] password for luca :   any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

if you know the software's name try 'dpkg -l | grep software' to find,then use 'sudo apt-get remove *  --purge' or 'sudo dpkg -r *'.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ubuntu tweak and purge the software sources you added,In Ubuntu Tweak 0.5.14, it is located in Package cleaner section

Comment: come elimino i software aggiunto, io uso lubuntu 11.10 lxde

Comment: English translation please.

Comment: @Prasad I know that I come a little late :) but, there you go: 
*How do I delete additional software, I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 lxde*

Comment: @Lucio please start a new question...you will get more answers :)

Comment: @Prasad No, you don't understand. I was translating the comment of #elvizz67. Haha, nevermind..

Comment: @Lucio Oh...sorry....please forgive me :D