# Why does an error appear every time I try to open the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, software-sources

There is a glitch on the Ubuntu Software Center and whenever I open it an error appears and it keeps loading and never opens.  Why does this happen?  I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a disk and partitioned it.  Please help me and ask for excess information if you need it.  If you know of any duplicates please show me them!!

I get the following error in a terminal

```
SystemError: E:Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
```

The `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` file contains a HTML document.

Comment: What is the error saying? Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: It would be better if you provide the errors you are getting. Although you can try this command in terminal once: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure software-center` Reply what did you get..

Comment: SystemError: E:Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list  I got this error doing both commands.  It happened on the first one then I tried the second one and this happened too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I remove a broken software source?](http://askubuntu.com/q/111585/65969)

Comment: If your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` file contains a full HTML page, then this is really not the content it should have. This really does not happen by itself - you probably have put it there without knowing what you were doing. Try removing the offending file. `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` and try again.

Comment: Also related: [How do I fix this “E:Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Answer (score 1):

The [Medibuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) repository, which is referred to in your SystemError output, has now been shut down, the packages were either obsolete, unnecessary or moved to the official Ubuntu archive. Now that you can no longer pull packages down from the Medibuntu archive, you no longer need the medibuntu.list file in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

1. Open the terminal and open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for editing in nano editor:

   ```
   sudo nano '/etc/apt/sources.list'
   ```

   Delete any lines in sources.list that have *medibuntu* in them. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the sources.list file. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
2. Remove the medibuntu.list file from its location in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. This command will create a backup directory and save a backup of the medibuntu.list file called medibuntu.list.bak in it:

   ```
   sudo mkdir backup && sudo mv '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list' '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backup/medibuntu.list.bak'
   ```
3. Tell your system to update the latest list of software from each archive it knows about:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Comment: I typed in the command and there weren't any lines that said medibuntu in them.  Can you give me any more help?

Comment: Maybe your sources.list file is OK the way it is, so it doesn't need to be edited. In that case step 1. doesn't apply because it does nothing, so skip step 1. and just do step 2. and step 3.

Comment: I tried step 2 and it said no such file exists.  Then I got step three and I got the original error.

Comment: I like [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories/192388#192388) by Anwar Shah. Following the instructions in that answer will restore your system back to the default repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command in a terminal

```
sudo sed 's/<!DOCTYPE//g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
```

Then check if it works with this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure software-center
```

If it doesn't work, then edit your question with the output of this command:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
```