# Why is medibuntu.org still offered as a package source if it has been shutdown since 2010?

Tags: apt

When trying an update, my output showed that "Some index files failed to download" and "They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."  Have I misconfigured something, or is there a reason why mediubuntu.org is still listed as an option if it has been shutdown?  Here is my update:

```
jeff@bigJeff:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en        
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org precise Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'packages.medibuntu.org'
Reading package lists... Done             
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'packages.medibuntu.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

uname -a

```
Linux bigJeff 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I was able to remove it from my sources list following the answer to this post:
[How do I remove a broken software source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111585/how-do-i-remove-a-broken-software-source)

This is a wiki last edited October 2013 explaining that it has been shutdown: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu

Once again, I am just looking to alleviate confusion for novices/newbies to Ubuntu, like myself, and promote good security practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obsolete sources that were added manually, need to be removed manually as well.  In Software Center I did the following to remove the source:

- Opened *Ubuntu Software Center*
- From the top menu selected *Edit* > *Software Sources*
- From the *Other Software* tab, unchecked the 2 entries for `packages.medibuntu.org`
- Selected both entries again/*Remove*

I can now update with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

Offered by who? Haven't you yourself added the medibuntu repository manually? Removing such repositories is entirely your responsibility.

Comment: If I added it, I don't remember doing so.  Do you know what it was useful for?  This does not answer my question.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu has never enabled Medibuntu repositories by default, so someone did. Presumably, it's you, or someone else with the admin access to the machine.