# Update Package Manager failed, E:type "ain"

Tags: updates, update-manager, scopes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix this “E:Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

The Update Manager failed and gave me this error:

> E:Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scopes-packagers-ppa-precise.list

What should I do?

This message came up when I followed the editor's instructions:

```
$cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scopes-packagers-ppa-precise.list
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu precise main
ain$
```

Comment: There is a problems with the scopes-packagers third-party software source, or with the way it's configured on your system. Please open a Terminal window (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`) and run this command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scopes-packagers-ppa-precise.list` Then select all the text in the Terminal (`Edit` > `Select All`), copy it to the clipboard (`Edit` > `Copy`). **Edit your question**, and paste it in. (You can highlight it as code with the `<$>` so that it is readable, as otherwise the formatting may be badly messed up.) That should provide the necessary information to solve your problem.

Comment: here a duplicate http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1987187