# Why does Update Manager fail with "`ain' not known on line 1" in sources.list?

Tags: updates, update-manager, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix this “E:Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

```
Could not initialise the package information 
 An unresolvable problem occurred while initialising the package information. 
 Please report this bug for the 'update-manager' package and try to include the following error message:  

'E:Type ‘ain’ is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/michael-gruz-canon-precise.list'
```