# Trouble installing iTunes and reading USB DVD Drive on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, iphone

I am new to Ubuntu and struggling with a few things:

An error occurred when checking for updates whilst trying to install something to read iTunes, or at least read music from iPhone.

I've got this red 'no entry' mark next to my message on tab.

Another problem - I tried to read USB DVD drive, but got following message:

```
E: Type ‘n’ is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-maverik.list
```

Comment: Could you type `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-maverik.list` and edit your question to include the output? This command displays the content of the `pmcenery-ppa-maverik.list` file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix this "E: Type '\*' is not known on line \* in source list ..." update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Answer (score 0):

iTunes can't be installed on Ubuntu.Try using some other music player such as RhythmBox or Amarock to manage the music on your iPhone.