# Ignoring file 'Untitled Document 1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension

Tags: update-manager

I get this message after trying the update manger:

```
W:Ignoring file 'Untitled Document 1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension,
E:Type 'eb' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ehoover-compholio-precise.list
```

I am new to Ubuntu. What should I do?

Comment: The cause is in the error message. You probably have been editing and adding file in system directories while you didn't know what you were doing. Please share the whole story.

Comment: What did you do to cause this error? `ehoover-compholio-precise.list` is not a standard source file so this has all come about from something you've done.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow a file called `Untitled Document 1` was copied to the `/etc/sources.list.d` folder. That's very odd. Such a file is usually a word processing document, and not a configuration file at all.

You can move this file to your desktop by opening a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Unt* ~/Desktop
```

Then the file will be on your desktop (in case it contains something important), and the first error message should go away. If it doesn't, please comment here and edit your question with details of what happened next.

The first message was actually a "warning"; it *might* work even if you leave `Untitled Document 1` in place,.

The second error message can be solved by following the instructions here:

- [How do I fix this "E: Type '*' is not known on line * in source list ..." update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)