# Synaptic and sudo apt-get update broken Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, synaptic

I just tried to build Riak unsuccessfully. Now something happened that messed everything up. When I try to start synaptic I get this:

```
E: Type '500' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho_riak.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Then when I try to run `sudo apt-get update` I get this again:

```
E: Type '500' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho_riak.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I also got an error saying something or other about line 500 during the build. Whatever I don't want Riak, I just want my Ubuntu fixed now.

And this is in etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho_riak.list:

```
500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix this "E: Type '\*' is not known on line \* in source list ..." update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you tried to install Riak something happened and the server that hosts the source/binaries had an internal error but the installation created the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho_riak.list` file anyway, even though it had no real link.

To fix the error just remove the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho_riak.list
```

Unfortunately this will mean you cannot install Riak in this way. What instructions did you follow? It may be a temporary error and might work later, but I rather doubt it.

Comment: Thank you everything works now. Well from their website site i tried a bunch of their directions and nothing was working so i tried there "build" instructions and that did not work either. How can i uninstall this ghost build ?

Comment: @bluerubez I'd have to see the instructions to tell you that. Do you have a direct link to what you followed? If my answer solved your problem [please accept it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179) to solve this topic.

Comment: Well this for starters did not work: https://packagecloud.io/basho/riak/packages/ubuntu/precise/riak_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Then i tried to install erlang which didnt work http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/erlang/#Installing-on-GNU-Linux

Comment: Im thinking there isn't a standard distribution for ubuntu 14.10 yet ?

Comment: @bluerubez Hmm, try running the commands in [this link](https://packagecloud.io/basho/riak/packages/ubuntu/precise/riak_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb) again, I just tested the 14.04 version and it worked. Also, about 14.10, it is up to the software author to release versions, I guess they just haven't updated their instructions yet.