# how solve update error 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04

am trying to update my stem and am getting this error problem

```
root@jay:/home/jay# apt-get update

E: Type 'eb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list

E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

any idea on how i can solve this?????

Comment: Can you upload the file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list`? It looks corrupted. If it's easier, [edit] the text into your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix this "E: Type '\*' is not known on line \* in source list ..." update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your file has been manually edited, or wrongly copy-pasted, and the keyword `deb` which should be at the beginning of the line is missing its first letter.

Try editing the file and replacing `eb` with `deb`, on the first word of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Only a wrong entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list`. Each line starts with `deb` or `deb-src`

Run the commands

```
sudo sed -i 's/^eb/deb/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list
sudo apt-get update
```