# Please help me with An error occurred, please run package manager

Tags: 16.04, spotify

I try to install `spotify` on my ubuntu 16.04 just very can't remember what I do and get the message.

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click
>   window or apt-get in a terminal to see what is
>   wrong.

The error message was:

> Error: opening the cache(E:Type 'sudo' is not know on line 1 in source list/etc/apt/sources/.list,E: the list of source could not be read.)'This usually means that you have >installed packages with unmet dependencies

I did not sure it this a problem too. I got something like this when I used code: `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo apt-get update
#deb-src http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
#deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Comment: Apparently you've messed up mentioned sources file. Please attach it's contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix this “E: Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update) and [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Thank you but it still problem, i might do something wrong again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-install the package with the missing dependencies first:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Should that fail, you'll have to purge spotify:

```
sudo apt-get purge spotify*
```

Comment: Thank you very much but It still not work for me .