# When I type sudo apt update into Linux beta I get an error

Tags: apt

The error is, 
"E: Type 'dab' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list 
E: The list of sources could not be read."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo on Line 3 of that file. Fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix this "E: Type '\*' is not known on line \* in source list ..." update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `grep -i dab /etc/apt/sources.list -B3 -A3`.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu 20.04, or something else? We don't support 20.04 until April, and we only support standard Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it's an issue with your /etc/apt/sources.list file. First open and check what your /etc/apt/sources.list file has.. using : cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Next open look for a typo in there. Ideally it should be 
"deb http://archive.offensive-security.com pwnsauce main microverse macroverse restricted universe multiverse" (without the quotation marks). Based on your question I guess your 'deb' has been misspelled as 'dab'. Once the typo is found, use a text editor and fix it.

Hope that helps. For more details check out this link https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1459830