# I can't get the app store icon

Tags: apt, software-sources, gnupg

I uninstalled some apps in Ubuntu 20.04 using the app store. After a while I tried to install a new program, but I can't get the app store icon anymore. The system is searching forever, but gives no error message. All other installed programs work fine.

`sudo apt update` gives the following:

```
E: Type "gpg" is unknown at line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics:darktable.list 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: That filename looks broken. There's a colon in it: `graphics:darktable.list` which is unusual. Did you rename that file? If so, rename it back to something like `darktable.list`. Then try `sudo apt update`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix this "E: Type '\*' is not known on line \* in source list ..." update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-e-type-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)